# Freshdesk API Create note with attachment throwing validation error

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle, freshdesk

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

function insert_freshdesk_note($ticketId, $content, $attachments=null)
{
    if(is_null($content)) {
        return false;
    }

    $url = 'https://mydomain.freshdesk.com/api/v2/tickets/'.$ticketId.'/notes';
    $method = 'POST';
    $userName = config('freshdesk_api_key');
    $password = 'password';

    $data = (!empty($attachments)) ? [
        "attachments[]" => $attachments,
        "body" => $content,
        "private" => false,
    ] : [
        "body" => $content,
        "private" => false,
    ];

    $options = (!empty($attachments)) ? [
        'json' => $data,
        'auth' => [$userName, $password],
        'headers' => ['content-type' => 'multipart/form-data']
    ] : [
        'json' => $data,
        'auth' => [$userName, $password]
    ];

    $client = new Client();

    try {
        $response = $client->request($method, $url, $options);
        return json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Log::error($e);
    }
}
```

Above code is working fine without attachments but when an attachment comes into the picture it's throwing the following error:-

```
GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `POST https://mydomain.freshdesk.com/api/v2/tickets/13033/notes` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
{"description":"Validation failed","errors":[{"field":"{\"attachments","message":"Unexpected/invalid field in request","
```

I am working according to the documentation and I have hit a dead end as of this point. I tried other permutations and combinations but via those, I wasn't able to resolve this problem.

Can anyone please help me.
Here is the link of the documentation of [freshdesk](https://developers.freshdesk.com/api/#introduction)
And in $attachments[] = '@/path/to/xyz.ext' this particular is going.

The function call will go like this:-

```
insert_freshdesk_note($this->freshdesk_ticket_id, $noteText, $image->image_full_path);
```

Comment: Where is the actual function call? We have no idea what you might be passing in as `$attachments` right now. Where is the link to the API documentation, so that we can see what you are supposed to send?

Comment: @CBroe I have updated the questions according to the things you've asked for. Let me know if there's any development. Thank You!

Comment: So does `$image->image_full_path` contain the `@` already? Don’t see you adding it anywhere. (`@filename` is “old” cURL syntax anyway, this should actually rather use `curl_file_create`, as is shown here, https://github.com/freshdesk/fresh-samples/blob/master/PHP/add_note_with_attachemnt.php#L12)

Comment: @CBroe I am using Guzzle HTTP Client to make the above code work.
I have already tried doing that way I got no resolution with it.
Thank You for your time I got this fixed I will be posting the answer soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the above question, I was trying to achieve the addition of note using GuzzleHTTP Client, Laravel Framework, and PHP language. Here's the following source code by which it starts working.

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

function insert_freshdesk_note($ticketId, $content, $attachments=null)
{   
    if(is_null($content)) {
        return false;
    }

    $url = 'https://mydomain.freshdesk.com/api/v2/tickets/'.$ticketId.'/notes';
    $method = 'POST';
    $userName = config('freshdesk_api_key');
    $password = 'password';

    $attachmentsFilePath = explode('/',$attachments);
    $fileName = end($attachmentsFilePath);

    $options = (!empty($attachments)) ? [
        'multipart' => [
            [
                'name'     => 'body',
                'contents' => $content,
            ],
            [
                'name'     => 'private',
                'contents' => "false",
            ],
            [
                'name'     => 'attachments[]',
                'contents' => fopen($attachments, 'r'),
                'filename' => $fileName,
            ],
        ],
        'auth' => [$userName, $password],
    ] : [
        'json' => [
            "body" => $content,
            "private" => false,
        ],
        'auth' => [$userName, $password]
    ];

    $client = new Client();

    try {
        $response = $client->request($method, $url, $options);
        return json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Log::error($e);
    }
}
```

We have to send the data in multipart fashion in order to Freshdesk backend to understand that data is there, by writing multipart/form-type in the header won't help. If you look at documentation also with and without attachments below:-

Without Attachment:-

```
curl -v -u user@yourcompany.com:test -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{ "body":"Hi tom, Still Angry", "private":false, "notify_emails":["tom@yourcompany.com"] }' 'https://domain.freshdesk.com/api/v2/tickets/3/notes'
```

With Attachment:-

```
curl -v -u user@yourcompany.com:test -F "attachments[]=@/path/to/attachment1.ext" -F "body=Hi tom, Still Angry" -F "notify_emails[]=tom@yourcompany.com" -X POST 'https://domain.freshdesk.com/api/v2/tickets/20/notes'
```

The difference in the curl can be seen.
This was the missing piece that I overlooked.